# A, B oder C + Verb im Singular / Plural

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

Wenn Subjektteile im Singular mit "oder" aufgelistet werden, sollte dann das Verb auch im Singular stehen oder ist der Plural auch in Ordnung? Konkret geht es um die Definition von Gebrauchstauglichkeit (Usability), die in den Normen DIN EN ISO 9241-210:2011-01 und E DIN EN ISO 9241-11:2017-01 unterschiedlich definiert ist:

Definition 1:

> **Gebrauchstauglichkeit (E DIN EN ISO 9241-11:2017-01)**
> Ausmaß, in dem ein System, ein Produkt oder eine
> Dienstleistung durch bestimmte Benutzer in einem bestimmten
> Nutzungskontext genutzt werden **können**, um festgelegte Ziele effektiv,
> effizient und zufriedenstellend zu erreichen

Definition 2:

> **Gebrauchstauglichkeit (DIN EN ISO 9241-210:2011-01)**
> Ausmaß, in dem ein System, ein Produkt oder eine Dienstleistung durch
> bestimmte Benutzer in einem bestimmten Nutzungskontext genutzt werden
> **kann**, um festgelegte Ziele effektiv, effizient und zufrieden-stellend
> zu erreichen.
>
> ANMERKUNG Von ISO 9241-11:1998 übernommen und angepasst.

Auf dieser [Seite](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-23240) wird beschrieben, dass normalerweise der Singular verwendet wird, allerdings steht dort nicht geschrieben, dass der Plural falsch ist. Ich zitiere in meiner Arbeit die erste Quelle (mit **können**) und wollte nachfragen, ob dies überhaupt grammatikalisch korrekt ist.

Comment: Auf der verlinkten Seite (canoo.net) steht doch ausdrücklich "Selten wird in diesen Fällen die Verbform im Plural verwendet" - was ist daran unklar?

Comment: Naja, dass ist ja keine richtige Begründung. Wenn etwas selten verwendet wird, kann es ja trotzdem falsch sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probieren wir's aus. Aber mit einem einfacheren, weniger abstrakten Beispiel als in der Frage, denn die Abstraktion verwirrt uns.

> Wie sieht's denn hier aus? Überall liegen Blätter rum! Der Hund, die Katze, der Maulwurf, der Fuchs oder die Ente **muss** mal den Waldboden fegen.

Hm. Geht zur Not. Klingt aber doch irgendwie falsch.

> Wie sieht's denn hier aus? Überall liegen Blätter rum! Der Hund, die Katze, der Maulwurf, der Fuchs oder die Ente **müssen** mal den Waldboden fegen.

Das klingt für mich besser.

Comment: Hah, für mich ist das genau anders herum! Denn im Prinzip ist das ein Appell an alle die Aufgezählten, dass einer von ihnen mal fegen **muss**, nicht aber, dass einer oder mehrere mal fegen **müssen**.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  Von der Logik her verstehe ich dich. Der Appell richtet sich an jedes einzelne Tier. Das spricht für Singular. Aber andererseits, wenn man weiterhin die Logik bemühen will: Wenn jedes Tier die Botschaft nur für sich selbst hört, fangen am Ende alle an, zu fegen, und das war ja nicht die Absicht des Waldhüters. Vielmehr sollen sie alle zusammen die Botschaft hören und dann in einem zookratischen Aushandlungsprozess festlegen, wer genau die Aufgabe verrichtet. Diese Botschaft (und die Verpflichtung) richtet sich an die *plurale Gesamtheit* der Tiere, darum besser ***müssen***.

Comment: Ich stimme Christian zu. Ob da nun *und* oder *oder* steht, macht keinen Unterschied. Die Gruppe ist gemeint.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist wohl eher eine Frage des Aspekts.

Def. 1 paraphrasiert: "Das Ausmaß, in dem die folgenden **drei Dinge** (generell) genutzt werden **können**"

Def. 2 paraphrasiert: "Das Ausmaß, in dem **jedes Ding** (für sich) genutzt werden **kann**."

Da die 'Dinge' selber jedoch weder die Nutzbarkeit noch das Ausmaß beeinflussen, optiere ich für Version 1.

Und füge hinzu, dass es neben der Frage des objektivierbaren Aspekts auch eine Frage der persönlichen Auffasung / des persönlichen Geschmacks sein dürfte.

Cheers!